# Form's element filter doesnt work

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I would like to add a filter to the text form element. The code is:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'product_amt', array(
    'filters' => array('Digits'),       
    'required' => true )
);
```

The filter seems not work because when i type e.g. "78abc" the value stays unchanged in the filed when i press the form submit button. Moreover i get "78abc" not "78" as "product_amt" POST parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value coming from POST will be the value the user has entered in the input field.
The filters are applied when you call `isValid` on the form object:

```
$form = new My_Form(); // your form object
if( $form->isValid( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) ) { //we pass in the POST data into the isValid function
    //Valid data - do something
} else {
    //data is not valid - do something else
}
```

During the `isValid` function, the value for each element is filtered as required (in this case into only Digits) then set as the elements' value before the elements' `isValid` function is called to make sure the value passes any validation (in this case 'isRequired' as you have set 'required' to true).

Are you calling `isValid` on your form?